# How to change the entry point of a Ios App?

Tags: swift, entry-point

I want to change my entry Point of my project but how I can do that? I don't use the storyboard, I do it all programmatically and I want my secondViewController to be the firstViewController.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: From AppDelegate `didfinishlaunchingwithoptions` method, you can set `secondViewController` as initial ViewController.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

without storyboard start with your specific ViewController put this code in `didfinishlaunchingwithOptions` method in `AppDelegate`.

```
let homeVC = SecondViewController()
self.window?.rootViewController = homeVC
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

with storyboard

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let homeVC = storyboard.instantiateInitialViewController()
self.window?.rootViewController = homeVC
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
```

Comment: Hey, it is not working, the old viewController is still the first one